# Jquery Use addclass in submit form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When submit form i need to run addclass and show loading animation and then run ajax
But when in ajax add false to async ,first run ajax and then loading anamiatin execute.

$('.form-login').submit(function(e) {

```
$('#alert-massages').html("").removeClass("alert alert-warning");
 $(".btn-login").addClass('loading');
 $(".btn-login").attr('disabled','disabled');

 if(formLogin.valid()) {

  $.ajax({
    url : "<%=checkOtpLoginUrl %>",
    dataType : "json",
    async: false,
    data : {
        "<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>msisdn" : $("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>msisdn").val(),
        "<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>password" : $("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>password").val(),
        "<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>captchaText" : $("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>captchaText").val(),
        "<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>rememberMe" : $("#<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() %>remember").val()},
    method : "post"

    }).done(function(data) {

        if (data.result) {
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `async: false`.  Ever.  It wouldn't surprise me if it's not even supported in recent browser updates.  Once you correct that, does the issue remain?

Comment: I need to use async : false

Comment: It's not a problem. It's the expected behaviour. Adding `async:false` (which you should _never_ do) forces your code to be synchronous, meaning everything freezes as long as the ajax call isn't finished (which is why you should never use it), therefore the loading animation doesn't show up until the end. Why do you _need_ to use `async:false`? What's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right here:

```
async: false
```

For one thing, this is deprecated (or at least quickly becoming deprecated?) and is unlikely to be supported in recent or future browser updates.  It's always been bad practice in the first place, and makes your code go against JavaScript principles.  Don't use it.

But **more to the point**, it explicitly tells your browser to make this asynchronous operation a *blocking call*.  What that means is the browser can't perform *any UI updates* until the operation completes.  Modifying the class of a DOM element is a UI update.  The underlying DOM itself is being updated, but the browser can't render that change on the screen until all blocking operations are complete.

Make your asynchronous operations asynchronous.  Remove `async: false`.  This will allow the browser to make the UI updates you want it to make.

If there's some *other* reason why you *think* you *need* to use `async: false`, then that's the actual problem you need to solve.  Currently your code is just hiding that problem by creating another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

While [$.addClass()](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js) is synchronous, css are applied with a bit of delay in the browser and when sync ajax call is done the browser is locked and can't repaint the new css appearence.

A workaround could be both to delay the ajax call in a setTimeout or make the ajax call async, which can solve istantly the issue.